# Line break (like <br>) using only css

Tags: html, css, styling

Is it possible in pure css, that is without adding additional html tags, to make a line break like `<br>`? I want the line break after the `<h4>` element, but not before:

HTML

```
<li>
  Text, text, text, text, text. <h4>Sub header</h4>
  Text, text, text, text, text.
</li>
```

CSS

```
h4 {
  display: inline;
}
```

I have found many questions like this, but always with answers like *"use display: block;"*, which I can't do, when the `<h4>` must stay on the same line.

Comment: Why is this element an h4? Why do you use it in a place like this?

Comment: Our of curiosity, what is the reason you don't want to use <br/>?

Comment: The reason: I have an awfull lot of list elements. And I was also wondering if an elegant solution exists. It is usually not nice to use br tags between elements (and I see the header as an element of its own)

Comment: @Tom, this is a simplified example. I have som text and headers in each list element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a line break before an element using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

It works like this:

```
h4 {
    display:inline;
}
h4:after {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bb2d7/

The trick comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000/509752 (to have more explanation)

Comment: `\a` means line break, character U+000A, and `white-space: pre` tells browsers to treat it as a line break in rendering.

Comment: Okay, thanks @JukkaK.Korpela. Then why isn't it rendered as a line break in the first place? Though this solution is simple, it still would override other white-space commands.

Comment: @Steeven, it only overrides the initial value for `white-space` on the `:after` pseudo-element, which contains just the line break. And it is needed because in HTML, by default, a line break in element content is equivalent to a space and does not cause a line break in the rendered document.

Comment: @Alshten, thanks, makes sense & totally weirds me out at the same time.

Comment: Would have never thought of this. It's a shame one can't insert HTML though!

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
h4{ display:block;}
```

in your css

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrJP6/

Comment: plus some judicious use of `margin-bottom` should get you there.

Comment: But if I understand well, the h4 has to be on the same line as the text before. With display:block, there's a line break before the h4.

Comment: What? `margin-bottom` will put the h4 at the same line as the preceding text?

Comment: !! This is not a working solution : your line after will be "display : none" in browsers like Safari !!

Comment: This creates a 'new line' above the element, so is not a solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to create a `0px`-height block after the `<h4>`, which effectively moves anything after the `<h4>` to the next line:

```css
h4 {
  display: inline;
}
h4::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Text, text, text, text, text. <h4>Sub header</h4>
    Text, text, text, text, text.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm late to the party but here's my two cents.

CSS

```
li h4 {
   break-after: always;
}

li h4::after {
   display: block;
   content: " ";
}
```