# How can I use CSS to insert a line break after but not before an element?

Tags: html, css, newline, pseudo-class, linefeed

For example:

HTML:

```
The quick brown fox <span class="break">{BREAK}</span> jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I want this to display:

> The quick brown fox {BREAK}
>
> jumps over the lazy dog.

I looked into the `display` property, but `display:inline;` doesn't break anywhere and `display:block` puts breaks on both sides.

I also looked into the `:after` pseudo-class, but `.break:after{content:"\000A";}` ends up rendering as a space, rather than a line feed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bMKrc/ Like this? You could also in that instance, just use divs.

Comment: @Jack No, without changing the HTML structure.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t just use `<br>` in HTML?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I want it to be customizable whether there is a line break or not.

Comment: SLaks solution is good, but you could just make the `span.break` display block. It's easier, less code, and cross browser compatible.http://jsfiddle.net/bMKrc/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line break (like <br>) using only css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933837/line-break-like-br-using-only-css)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, HTML elements ignore whitespace.
You need to [change that](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/pf8eM/):

```
.break:after {
    content:"\000A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I will accept as soon as the 15 minutes is up.

Comment: in my case it did not work unless i put text in it why?!

Comment: @shareef: What are you talking about? What happened?

Comment: @Slaks Could you explain what this is doing please?  I've just come across the answer, and it works, but I want to understand what it's doing.  (Please and thank you :))

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/bMKrc/1/

html:

`The quick brown fox <span class="break"></span> jumps over the lazy dog`.

CSS:

```
.break{
    display:block;
}
```

And that's all you need. `display:block` may cause it to break on both sides, but it does not cause there to be an extra line. View my fiddle.

Comment: @Matt Just because the OP says something does not mean it's true. You achieve the desired result with display block. Check out my fiddle if you don't believe me.

Comment: In case it was confusing "{BREAK}" is still supposed to be part of the text.

Comment: Oh, that does not make much sense, but it's not my project. I thought he was showing where to put the break. But that does not warrant your being rude.

Comment: Ok, I appologize if I came off as rude. The reason it does not make much sense is because I only gave an illustrative example of my problem and not my actual problem.

Comment: The jsfiddle.net makes it very clear. I tried many many ways to put a line break between an img and an Angular {{ }} binding that are both inside a button, and this is the only thing that works. And its so self explanatory in the code, especially if you call the class lineBreak.

Comment: ..soo, why don't use <br> then?