# How to force soft wrap from a custom-made ACE editor mode?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm writing a custom mode for the [ACE editor](https://ace.c9.io/) to support my toy template language.

In the language there is a construct to embed a newline:

```
foo{\n}bar
```

It will be rendered with a newline, as follows:

```
foo
bar
```

I would like to imitate this in the editor and force a soft wrap after `{\n}`:

```
1 | foo{\n}
  | bar
```

Is there a way to do this in my mode?

Update: FWIW, here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/agladysh/f86c806cd82772cd9846d2638ee28d12) to my mode file.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's a bit hard to reproduce **[EDIT: see below]**, but according to [the class diagram](https://ace.c9.io/#apiHolder), you need to interact with the [VirtualRenderer](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js) to alter how things are displayed.

It takes a [theme](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/4a55188fdb0eee9e2d3854f175e67408a1e47655/lib/ace/theme) to style the code. (you can select these in [the editor](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) at the `Theme`-menu). Themes are `css` (+`js`) files, which opens the possibility of using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933837/line-break-like-br-using-only-css) to insert a newline after your `{\n}` element class.

**EDIT: code was added**

Depending on the position of the `\n` (several parts of the regex could match), you might be able to use

```
{
    token: function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7) {
      return [
        "constant",
        "keyword.operator",
        (arg3 === '\n') ? "newline" : "variable.parameter",
        "keyword.operator",
        "string",
        "keyword.operator",
        "variable"
      ],
    regex: /([%]?)([=]?)([^|>}]*)([|]?)([^>}]*)([>]?)([^}]*)/
}
```

and then have

```
.ace_newline:after {
  content:"\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

in your custom theme.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your class diagram link seems to be broken. I considered the CSS approach, but I am not sure it will not break other logic for ACE. Have to try it though. NB: see also this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ace-discuss/Xsfb4SSMxAs/KMKXdP-IAwAJ