# visualize line-break and paragraph break with symbols in html similar to word

Tags: html, css

Is it anyhow possible to visualize line break and paragraph breaks symbols in html, like in word?

[image]

Comment: I wrote my answer assuming that you have some existing HTML markup consisting of `<p>` and `<br>` elements. However, maybe you are actually trying to accomplish this within a `<textarea>` or similar, trying to create a text editor of some sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As far as I know, the answer is *yes and no* for CSS only, *yes* for CSS & JavaScript.**

For the end of the paragraph, the `::after` selector comes to the rescue:

```css
p::after {
  content: "¶";
  color: #6495ED;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a pragraph.</p>
<p>Here goes another paragraph.</p>
```

However, this does not reliably work on `<br>`, unless you want to use JavaScript (see below).
Check these questions for further details on the issue:

- ["Can you target `<br \>` with css?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css)
- ["Line break (like `<br>`) using only css"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933837/line-break-like-br-using-only-css)

---

#### CSS only (not cross browser compatible)

This CSS only solution works for me on the following browsers (Windows 10):
Chrome 56 and Opera 43. It does not work on Firefox 51, IE 11 or Edge 38.

```css
br {
  content: " ";
}

br::after {
  content: "↵\a";
  white-space: pre;
  color: #6495ED;
}

p::after {
  content: "¶";
  color: #6495ED;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a pragraph with two sentences.<br>This is the second sentence, it follows a line break.</p>
<p>Here goes another paragraph.</p>
```

---

#### CSS & JavaScript solution (cross browser)

If you are okay with using JavaScript, here is my vanilla approach.
Disclaimer: I'm not experienced with JS, maybe there is a better way.
For me, this works with all of the browsers mentioned above.

```js
var spanbr = document.createElement("span");
spanbr.className = "br";

var brs = document.getElementsByTagName("br");

for (var i = 0; i < brs.length; ++i) {
  brs[i].parentElement.insertBefore(spanbr, brs[i]);
}
```

```css
.br::after {
  content: "↵";
  color: #6495ED;
}

p::after {
  content: "¶";
  color: #6495ED;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a pragraph with two sentences.<br>This is the second sentence, it follows a line break.</p>
<p>Here goes another paragraph.</p>
```