# Line break after input using only css

Tags: html, css, carriage-return

I got a html with a lot of label + input

```
<label>Application</label>
<input id="ApplicationName" />
...
<label>Foo</label>
<input id="Foo" />
...
<label>Junk</label>
<input id="Junk" />
```

I force a width to add some consistency

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
}
input {
    width: 10em;
}
```

With this style it's a bit better but the flow still breaks "anywhere" depending on the width of container. How can I make the label + input to be a block ?
(Without enclosing both of them in a container)

Another acceptable solution would be to
 [add a virtual carriage return after each input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933837/line-break-like-br-using-only-css) or
 [before each label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363766/how-to-insert-a-line-break-before-an-element-using-css).
I didn't succeed to put it after because the input tag doesn't support after.
Neither can I put it before because

```
label::before {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

doesn't mix well with label{display:inline-block}

```css
label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:10em;
}

input {
    width:10em;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>namespace</label>
    <input id="namespace" />
            
    <label>Application</label>
    <input id="application" />
            
    <label>Description</label>
    <input id="Description" />
            
    <label>Author</label>
    <input id="Author" />
</div>
resize the window to exhibit unwanted behaviour
```

Comment: Enclosing them inside a container with `display:inline-block` could be the best solution. Why you don't want to use that solution?

Comment: The `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: Here you go: `label:before { content: "\a"; white-space: pre; }` - messy, but it works. I've added a couple of other options and explanation into my answer for you.

Comment: I don't have control over the html. And, as this could possibly updated dynamically it'll hard to fix. And it's easier to read without container :)

Comment: @Rob. Who knows. Maybe it's xhtml ? :)

Comment: I guarantee it's not xhtml.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mixture of floating and clearing, a bit old school but seems to work for the structure:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  float: left; /* makes the element act like inline block */
  clear: left; /* clears any left floats so before so this should start on new line */
}

input {
  width: 10em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>namespace</label>
  <input id="namespace" />

  <label>Application</label>
  <input id="application" />

  <label>Description</label>
  <input id="Description" />

  <label>Author</label>
  <input id="Author" />
</div>
```

Or you could just give a width to your parent container to force the content onto the next line:

```css
div {
  width: 21em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}

input {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>namespace</label>
  <input id="namespace" />

  <label>Application</label>
  <input id="application" />

  <label>Description</label>
  <input id="Description" />

  <label>Author</label>
  <input id="Author" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1, CSS-only

If you really can't edit the HTML, then you can apply `white-space: pre;` and `content: "\a";` to the `label:before`. See [this updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsjd3w8L/3/).

```css
label:before {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<label>Application</label>
<input id="ApplicationName" />

<label>Foo</label>
<input id="Foo" />

<label>Junk</label>
<input id="Junk" />
```

### Option #2, HTML-only

A better solution could be to just wrap the `<input>`s in the `<label>`s (another  benefit of this, is that you don't need to use the `for` attribute to link each label the the corresponding input!). Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsjd3w8L/1/) with your code snippet :)

```css
input{
  width: 10em;
}

label{
  float: left; 
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<label>Application: <input id="ApplicationName" /></label>
        
<label>Foo: <input id="Foo" /></label>

<label>Junk: <input id="Junk" /></label>
```

Comment: I don't think it will help : I want label to be on the left and input on the right. With this I'll get : label<br />input label<br/>input label<br/>... and I want label input<br/>label input<br/>label input<br/>

Comment: Yeah. It would probably better to do it that way but I got little or no way to alter the html.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misunderstood you- I've updated the answer to also provide a method without changing the HTML :) Does that help?

Comment: thank you for your jsfiddle but this doesn't adress the problem of fixed width for label. I used Pete's solution