# Dividing the paragraph HTML

Tags: html, string, paragraph

I am currently creating a site. I have one `<p>` that i have to divide for different strings.

Here is the code:

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum - <strong style="color: red;">something.</strong> 
  Lorem ipsum - <strong style="color:blue">something.</strong>\n
  Lorem ipsum - <strong style="color: black;">something.</strong> 
  More lorem ipsum: <strong style="color: indigo;">pls help.</strong>
  Stackoverflow: <strong style="color: purple;">is cool.</strong>
</p>
```

I want it to make a new line after every `<strong>` tag, but it outputs a single line.
I tried \n, but it doesn't work.

Also please don't ask me to divide it to 3 or 4 paragraphs, I shouldn't do it for this code.

Comment: By the way, the code actually doesn't look that ugly, it has some tabs before all  the strings so StackOverFlow shows it like this.

Comment: use `<br/>` tag which means break line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break (like <br>) using only css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933837/line-break-like-br-using-only-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\n isn't for HTML. Try using `<br>`.
How to use:

`<p>Hello! <br /> How are you? <p>`

What it outputs:

```
Hello!
How are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<br/>` as demkovych suggests.

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum - <strong style="color: red;">something.</strong><br/>
  Lorem ipsum - <strong style="color:blue">something.</strong><br/>
  Lorem ipsum - <strong style="color: black;">something.</strong><br/>
  More lorem ipsum: <strong style="color: indigo;">pls help.</strong><br/>
  Stackoverflow: <strong style="color: purple;">is cool.</strong><br/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to have a `<br/>` tag after every strong tag. However, a better practice is to add this styling in CSS. The `p` tag could be styled like this:

```css
p {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

See also the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)  for the `white-space` property.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be an interesting problem and I've expanded upon it a little.

The first step was to add a class to the P tag, so we could differentiate and reuse the styling for other similar paragraphs.

Then, based on the requirement that we want to stylistically  replace `</strong>` with `</strong><br/>` in this paragraph class only, I hit up the ::after pseudo element on strong tags within that paragraph class.

```
p.multicolor strong::after { 
 content: "\A";
 white-space: pre; 
}
```

Then, Just for the heck of it, I added the colors.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 

p.multicolor strong::after { 
 content: "\A";
 white-space: pre; 
}
p.multicolor strong:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
  color: red;
}
p.multicolor strong:nth-of-type(5n+2) {
  color: blue;
}
p.multicolor strong:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
  color: black;
}
p.multicolor strong:nth-of-type(5n+4) {
  color: indigo;
}
p.multicolor strong:nth-of-type(5n) {
  color: purple;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="multicolor">
 Lorem ipsum - 
<strong> something</strong>
 Lorem ipsum - 
<strong> something</strong>
Lorem ipsum - 
<strong> something</strong>
More lorem ipsum: 
<strong> pls help.</strong>
Lorem ipsum - 
<strong> is cool.</strong>
Out of colors :
<strong> start over from red </strong>
Continuing : 
<strong> should be blue </strong>
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: LOL the best answer! Not just <br /> but something interesting. Love you Chris Cudmore

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\n`, use `<br>`, it will solve your problem. People use `\n` on programming languages such as C and Python, for example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I already answered an hour ago!

Answer (score 0):

consider multi-column layout,

this is documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).