# RWD, using ONLY CSS + "attribute content" is possible write TAGS?

Tags: css

it is totally different to [Line break (like <br>) using only css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933837/line-break-like-br-using-only-css)

I need:

```
/* in window FULL */
.contentbreak{
content:'';
}

/* in window PHONE */
.contentbreak{
content:'<br />';
}
```

but maybe I also need usedOTHERS tags.

is possible without use JavaScript ?

Comment: "it is totally different" - how so? what is the actual issue you're struggling with or what is your desired output?

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. What's there doesn't make much sense in isolation.

Comment: thanks, I repeat: using `only CSS + "attribute content"` is possible write tags?, by example `<br />` or others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```html
<br class="mobile">
```

with according css styles:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: XYZpx)  {
/*XYZ: your breakpoint; every value bigger than the one here would hide line break*/
        .mobile {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Another possibility (pure CSS):

```css
@media screen and (min-width: XYZpx)  {
    #content::after{
    /* #content is the line before line break */
        content: "\a";
        white-space: pre;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, then using `only CSS` not is possible write TAGS ?

Comment: @Stackoverflow you can also use vanilla CSS, I edited the answer for you